# Error with Tomcat instance in Intellij 13

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea

The error I am getting:

```
ERROR ContextLoader - Context initialization failed []
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'cronTriggerLoggerFlush' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-job.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'instance.group'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:220)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:84)
    at com.containerstore.core.spring.EnvironmentProperties.postProcessBeanFactory(EnvironmentProperties.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:656)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.extensibility.web.MergeContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(MergeContextLoader.java:104)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.extensibility.web.MergeContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(MergeContextLoader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:281)
    at org.broadleafcommerce.extensibility.web.MergeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(MergeContextLoaderListener.java:41)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1429)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:835)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:631)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:568)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:295)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:835)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:771)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1455)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:75)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1296)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1388)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:819)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:303)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Jun 29, 2014 10:27:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jun 29, 2014 10:27:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
```

Any ideas on the missing part or what is causing the error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the parameter 'instance.group' is missing in the property file

Comment: How do I go about adding it?

Comment: @studiobrain add it to the file where the propertyconfigurer point to. and add `instance.group = yourValue`

Comment: Accepting your answer as it technically answers my question of whats the error...  My issue however is within VM setup, and is being solved on server-side...